# Looping through rows inside function

Tags: sql, database, postgresql-9.1

Can someone please help with with a SQL function. I need to have a function that can loop and execute a query with different date in every loop. I want to check the field if not null then return the field or row, if null I want to continue the loop with different.

Here is an example of what I want:

```
create or replace function getCounterValue(id integer, datee text) RETURNS varchar(20) AS $$
DECLARE
  cvalue varchar(20);

BEGIN
  for x IN 1..365 LOOP
    select cr.counter_value into cvalue
    from snmp_printer p 
      left join snmp_counters_scan cs on(p.id=cs.printer)
      left join snmp_printer_model pm on(p.model=pm.id)
      left join snmp_counter c on (pm.id=c.model)
      left join snmp_counters_result cr
        on (cr.snmp_counter=c.id and cr.counters_scan=cs.id)
    where p.id = id
      and c.name='PAGE COUNT'
      and cs.id in (select max(pp.id) from snmp_counters_scan pp
                    where pp.scan_date <= cast(datee as date) -interval x ||'day'
                    group by printer);

    if cvalue is not null then 
        return cvalue;  
    else 
    --continue
    end if;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN cvalue;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Move the c conditions from WHERE to c's ON to get true left join behavior. (Now that left join executes as a regular inner join...)

Comment: What you're really looking for is a [tag:greatest-n-per-group] (here, `n` is one) to get the "earliest" `snmp_counters_scan` row.  For best results, you'd probably want that as a CTE or subquery (so you're not partitioning the entire data set).  However, the not-`LEFT JOIN`s are confusing things (I don't know what should actually be turned into a regular join, instead of what's _actually_ being transformed, like @jarlh says).  If you're looping in SQL, usually you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use SCROLL CURSOR or use [APPLY](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) operator.